# Extract text from script using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

Im getting this script from my crawler:

```
        [{"display_name":"AERIN","status":4,"value":5024296}],"type":"checkboxes"},{"display_name":"Bristle Type","values":[{"display_name":"Addictive","status":1,"value":14578019},{"display_name":"Chic","status":1,"value":14301148}],"type":"checkboxes"},{"display_name":"Coverage","values":
```

.
.
.

How do I extract the text after [{"display_name":  ?

Comment: That looks like it’s probably some JSON you extracted out of your soup. If so, you want to parse it with `things=json.loads(thatstring)`. Then, you’ll have a list of dicts. If you know the list always has exactly one element, it’s just `things[0]['display_name']`. If you don’t know that, you probably want to loop `for thing in things:` and then do something with `thing['display_name']`.

Comment: thanks! Can you explain a little more. Json is new for me. I have to include import json, right? I included these lines following your instuctions:
jsons =json.loads(productoslvl)
        element = jsons[0]['display_name']
        print (element)

However, I am getting the error line 348, in loads
    'not {!r}'.format(s.__class__.__name__))

Comment: Yes, you have to import it. See the docs page for the module for some good examples. It’s hard to help you debug your problem without more context. If you can provide a [mcve], either as a new question or edited into this one, with code and sample data that demonstrates the problem (ideally creating a soup out of a small, static string literal that has just enough of the HTML to demonstrate how you get this string out and then try to parse it), that should be easy to debug.

Comment: Also, if the error says this is invalid JSON, you should try copying and pasting it into an online JSON validator (I don’t have a particular one to recommend, but there are lots of them on a web search and they all seem fine), and you may need to include info on where you got it from (e.g., a script that downloads the page from a URL, then makes a soup out of it)—e.g., maybe it’s not JSON, but just something that coincidentally looks very similar, in which case nobody would be able to tell that without seeing where it comes from).

Comment: Thanks for the help! It gave me a lot of light on the next steps. Still I have no clue on how to extract the data. I posted another question with the details.